# Proving $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-1}\left[\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi km}{N}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)}\right]^{2}=m(N-m)$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, closed-form, trigonometric-series

I recently came across a sum (whose closed-form solution I was able to verify via Wolfram Alpha) but have no idea how to get there.

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N-1}\left[\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi km}{N}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{N}\right)}\right]^{2}=m(N-m)$$

I'm pretty sure it's valid for any $m\in 0,1,2\ldots N-1$ and $N\geq2$

My only ideas were to make exponential substitutions or to bring an integral into the mix like this one $$\frac{\pi^{2}}{\sin^{2}(\pi s)}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{1-x}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\mathrm dx$$

I couldn't get very far. I figure there's a better way to simplify the fraction of sine functions since they differ only by a dilation of $m$. Let me know what you guys think!

Comment: The following trig identity (from Wikipedia's page on the [Fejér kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fejér_kernel)) seems suggestive: $$\left({\frac  {\sin {\frac  {nx}{2}}}{\sin {\frac  {x}{2}}}}\right)^{2}={\frac  {1-\cos(nx)}{1-\cos x}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $\sum_{q=0}^{m-1}D_q(x)=\left({\frac  {\sin {\frac  {mx}{2}}}{\sin {\frac  {x}{2}}}}\right)^{2}$, where $D_q(x)=\sum_{|j| \le q}e^{ijx}$ is the Dirichlet Kernel, we can rewrite the original sum as:

$S_{m,N}=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\sum_{q=0}^{m-1}\sum_{|j| \le q}e^{\frac{2\pi ijk}{N}}$, where $0 \le m \le N-1$ fixed.

Fixing now $0 \le |j| \le m-1$ and bringing the terms with $j$ together, we get:

$S_{m,N}=\sum_{|j| \le m-1}((m-|j|)\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}e^{\frac{2\pi ijk}{N}})$

But now the term $j=0$ is obviously $m(N-1)$ while all the other inner exponential sums are $-1$ since $0<|j|<N$, hence we get

$S_{m,N}=m(N-1)-\sum_{0<|j| \le m-1}(m-|j|)=m(N-1)-m(m-1)=m(N-m)$

so we are done!

Comment: very nice! Haha, I was looking at Semiclassical's comment and plunged right into Wikipedia's articles on Fejer kernels which led me to Dirichlet's kernel as well. I've never worked with these things before, have only heard of them once before. I'll start researching more and have your answer as my starting point! Awesome! Do you mind if I share your solution on Quora as well (giving you credit and linking this post) as part of a larger post of mine on a different sum where this popped up?

Comment: happy to be of help!

Comment: My apologies, I had edited my comment but you had already responded. Do let me know if it's permissible to share your approach, and have a great day!

Comment: Sure no problem